# C++ executable - MSVCR100.dll not found error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, package, redistributable, msvcr100.dll

I've downloaded and compiled an open-source C++ application, [Frhed](http://frhed.sourceforge.net/en/).

When I run the version I've compiled, it demands MSVCR100 and few other dll files (part of Visual C++ redistributable). However, when I run the original precompiled Frhed executable, it runs without any C++ redistributable package installed.

Do I have to modify any compilation options in order to unlink the program from the C++ redistributable libraries?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The original program is probably **statically linked**, whereas you are trying to dynamically link your executable, which results in a smaller file, but a dependency on functions inside `MSVCR100.dll` (v10 of the Microsoft C Runtime Library), which would have been included inside the executable if you were statically linking.

To statically link DLLs, go into your project properties and change the build mode from `MD` to `MT`. In Visual Studio 2010/2012, that project property is C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is **yes**, the longer answer is, well, longer.

The library `msvcr100.dll` is the **10.0** version (i.e., Visual Studio 2010 version) of the [DLL implementation of the C run-time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx) which you probably requested by using the /MD compile option.  To avoid using the dynamically linked version of the run-time you can use the /MT option instead and statically link the run-time.

Alternatively, you can [redistribute msvcr100.dll (and other files)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx) along with your program.