# Visual Studio C++ 2010. Run exe without redristibutable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a fully statically linked .exe with Visual Studio Express 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398/how-do-i-make-a-fully-statically-linked-exe-with-visual-studio-express-2005)

I've noticed that if you try to run a program compiled with VSC++ you need to have the redristibutable insalled. Is there any way to make your exe only need the library you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a program without parts of the runtime library which is inside the redistributable. However, you can statically link the redist into the exe. See here: [C++ executable - MSVCR100.dll not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976940/c-executable-msvcr100-dll-not-found-error)

Comment: Not true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398/how-do-i-make-a-fully-statically-linked-exe-with-visual-studio-express-2005

Comment: Does the redistributable only reffer to MSVCR100.dll? If so, i think i can give this file along with my .exe. Or does the copyright stop me from doing this?

Comment: That's what the redistributable is for - you can redistribute it to your customers. @EricJ.: care to elaborate what's the difference between what I said and the answer to the question you linked?

Comment: You cannot "link the redist", a DLL is not a linkable item.